# Returning #N/A when using IFS with MATCH

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using `IFS` and `MATCH` in this function below to select a specific value from a condition, but it is returning error.

```
IFS(MATCH(C4, A2, 0), A3, MATCH(C4, A3, 0), A2, MATCH(C4, B2, 0), B3, MATCH(C4, B3, 0), B2)
```

I've noticed that when reordering the formula above to the one below, if the `MATCH`condition that returns `TRUE` comes first, `IFS` will read it first and output the expected value `E`; so it's probably some issue with the other "MATCHes" not finding the `C4` value in the condition and returning `#N/A`, as you can see in [this spreadsheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N7kziyP9cXutGPQOvZGjEZzC5jWo1uHxMhseBgQfgco).

```
IFS(MATCH(C4, B2, 0), B3, MATCH(C4, A2, 0), A3, MATCH(C4, A3, 0), A2, MATCH(C4, B3, 0), B2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a logical_test argument is evaluated and resolves to a value other than `TRUE or FALSE`, this function `returns a #VALUE! error` so I added `isnumber function` so its result only `true or false`, Now maybe it will work, try this formula

```
E3=IFS(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C4, A2, 0)), A3, ISNUMBER(MATCH(C4, A3, 0)), A2, ISNUMBER(MATCH(C4, B2, 0)), B3, ISNUMBER(MATCH(C4, B3, 0)), B2)
```

or

```
E3=IFS(C4=A2,A3,C4=A3,A2,C4=B2,B3,C4=B3,B2)
```

[image]

Comment: The first formula wouldn't work because the variables are actually letters, but the second one works just fine. I don't know how I didn't think in this before. Simple and efficient. Thank you!

Comment: @luiz the `variables are letters` but the match will still work, because `match returns a number or error` so `isnumber` simply checks it and return `true or false`. I think it will still work for you

Answer (score 0):

As per your example, please try below formula.

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(C4,A2:A3,0),MATCH(C4,B2:B3,0))
```

Comment: Hello, @Harun24HR! I tested your formula, but it's returning TRUE/FALSE only. I tried to use the `search_type` as you did in your formula, but nothing happens still.

Comment: @Luiz See your example sheet posted here. I have put the formula to your google sheet and it is returning 1.

Comment: Yes, it's returning 1 as TRUE, but the problem persists when trying to return the letter E.

Comment: Then what is your actual goal? Can you put your expected out to the post?